# why cant i instantiate the type node?

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures

i created a simple single linked list program using java in eclipse.i have created a main class and 2 class files node.java and linkedlist.java but i cant instantiate the type node,but my node class is not static.why cant i instantiate type node?

```
app.java
package linkedlist.singlelinkedlist;
This is my main class
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class app 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
        list.insert(10);
        list.insert(15);
        list.insert(20);
        list.show();

    }
}
node.java
This is my node class file
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

}

linkedlist.java
```

This is my LinkedList class file

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    public void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node=new Node();#why cant i instantiate node?
        node.data=data;
        node.next=null;
        if(head==null)
        {
            head=node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node n=head;
            while(n.next!=null)
            {
                n=n.next;
            }
            n.next=node;
        }
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Node x=head;``
        while(x.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(x.data);
            x=x.next;
        }
        System.out.println(x.data);
    }

}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot instantiate the type Node
    data cannot be resolved or is not a field
    next cannot be resolved or is not a field
    next cannot be resolved or is not a field
    next cannot be resolved or is not a field
    next cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at linkedlist.singlelinkedlist.LinkedList.insert(LinkedList.java:9)
    at linkedlist.singlelinkedlist.app.main(app.java:13)
Hello World!
```

how to instantiate the type node and to rectify the error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - you can't run code that contains errors. Look at the errors Eclipse is telling you about and fix them.

Answer (score -1):

I just compiled your code, and it is working fine.

NOTE: LinkedList is also a native Java class. Make sure that your program is not pointing to the native class instead of your class.

Code:

```
package me.PauMAVA.Tests;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
        list.insert(10);
        list.insert(15);
        list.insert(20);
        list.show();

    }
}
```

```
package me.PauMAVA.Tests;

public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    public void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node=new Node();
        node.data=data;
        node.next=null;
        if(head==null)
        {
            head=node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node n=head;
            while(n.next!=null)
            {
                n=n.next;
            }
            n.next=node;
        }
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Node x=head;
        while(x.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(x.data);
            x=x.next;
        }
        System.out.println(x.data);
    }

}
```

```
package me.PauMAVA.Tests;

public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
10
15
20
```